# How to collect a date from user, add days to it, and store answer as UNIX time?

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a form that collects 4 pieces of info. My goal is to calculate a 5th piece of info (launch date) from that info.

1. Start Date (YYYY-MM-DD)
2. Dev days
3. QA days
4. Release days

I need to sum the integer input from 2-4 and add those input from 1. I can't get this to work correctly though and I would appreciate any pointers.

Code that collects form input:

```
$start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
$dev_days = $_POST['dev_days'];
$qa_days = $_POST['qa_days'];
$release_days = $_POST['release_days'];
```

Code that calculates launch date:

```
$start_date = strtotime($start_date);
$feature_days = $dev_days + $qa_days + $release_days;
$feature_days = $feature_days * (60*60*24);
$launch_date = strtotime($start_date, $feature_days);
```

Comment: Why doesn't `$start_date + $feature_days` work? Shouldn't that give you the (approximate) UNIX timestamp of the launch date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that you need (instead of your 4 lines) is

```
$launch_date  = strtotime($start_date . ' +' .
                               ($dev_days + $qa_days + $release_days) . ' day');
```

In your code (if you want to leave it "as is" and to use your own version) the last line should be

```
$launch_date = $start_date + $feature_days;
```

Comment: @Alnitak       read my answer more carefully. I gave him alternative version of the code and also mentioned about an error in his code.

Comment: it would have helpd if you wrapped your code so the relative format could be seen without scrolling

Comment: @Alnitak       Thanks :) I actually tried different variants, but none of them was suitable to me. Wrapped the code..